# Gradle Multi-Project with Subversion

Tags: svn, gradle

I have a SVN repo that has the following structure for a multi-project:

```
|--root-project
|    |--trunk
|    |    |--src
|    |    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--branches
|    |    |--1
|    |
|    |--tags
|    |    |--release1.0
|    |
|    |--project-a
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |--branches
|    |         |--1
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--release1.0
|    |    |    |--release1.1
|    |
|    |--project-b
|    |    |--trunk
|    |    |    |--src
|    |    |    |--build.gradle
|    |    |--branches
|    |         |--1
|    |    |--tags
|    |    |    |--release1.0
|    |
|    |-- common
|    |    |--project-c
|    |    |      |--trunk
|    |    |      |     |--src
|    |    |      |     |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |    |      |--branches
|    |    |      | --tags
|    |    |      |     |--release1.0
```

project-a and project-b depend on project-c. The directory structure needs to be as follows to model the examples on https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html:

```
|--root-project
|    |--src
|    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--project-a
|    |    |--src
|    |    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--project-b
|    |    |--src
|    |    |--build.gradle
|    |
|    |--project-c
|    |--src
|    |--build.gradle
```

Can I use gradle multi-project support with the SVN repo structure that I currently have? Or do the SVN repo directories need to be restructured to support gradle multi-projects? Or should the directories be restructured to better follow best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a killer feature included in Gradle 3.1 called [composite build support](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes#composite-builds). It should do everything you need. This feature is a game changer!! User guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)

Other options include:

1. Use continuous integration (eg [travis](https://travis-ci.org/) or [jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins)) to publish project artifacts (jars) to an artifact repository (eg [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/) or [nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/products-sonatype)) and reference the artifacts rather than source code
2. Build a project and publish artifacts (jars) to a local repository and reference from there (eg [publishing to maven local](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install))
3. [Prezi Pride](https://github.com/prezi/pride)